# Why is normal differentiation correct here when the function has 2 variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

**Background:**
I was studying about [Four velocity (Special Relativity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) and was trying to understand the derivation of relation between 3-dimensional velocity and Four velocity from [Proff. Leonard Susskind's 3rd lecture](https://youtu.be/_R6J8Wb1Xek). While doing this I came at 26:40 and immediately got confused due to my reasoning clashing with what was occuring.

**Question:**
The variable $\tau$ depends on 2 variables $t$ and $x$. With the relation $\tau^2 = t^2 - |\vec{x}|^2$, where $|\vec{x}|^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$. We want to find the term $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$.

Now my confusion starts with me seeing $\tau^2=t^2-|\vec{x}|^2$ as multivariable function and so $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$ doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Then secondly when I ignored the $d$ and do my (in my mind) more logical $\delta$. I get the wrong result...

*Calulation:*
$$\tau = \sqrt{t^2 - |\vec{x}|^2}$$
$$\frac{\delta \tau}{\delta t} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \times 2t}{\sqrt{t^2 - |\vec{x}|^2}}$$
$$\frac{\delta \tau}{\delta t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{|\vec{x}|^2}{t^2}}}$$
$$\frac{\delta \tau}{\delta t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - |\vec{v}|^2}}$$
So this $\frac{\delta \tau}{\delta t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - |\vec{v}|^2}}$ is what I have got but in the video lectures proffesor got the inverse result through these calculations:
$$\tau = \sqrt{t^2 - |\vec{x}|^2}$$
$$d\tau = \sqrt{{dt}^2 - |\vec{dx}|^2}$$
$$d\tau = dt\sqrt{1 - \frac{|\vec{dx}|^2}{{dt}^2} }$$
$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - |\vec{v}|^2 }$$

Now I kinda understand that the first $|\vec{v}|$ is fixed and represents average velocity but does $|\vec{v}|$ in second one represent instantaneous? I only have some vague idea that in second method we say that we are comparing very small changes in all three variables.

I summary why is my method wrong, and what are we exactly doing in the second method?

Comment: Here's some general advice about those lectures: don't rely on Susskind's videos for rigor or consistently correct/accurate mathematics. Treat those lectures as a movie/documentary: watch for fun, learn as much as possible (you can definitely learn a lot), and ignore things (or atleast take details wiyh a grain of salt) which don't make sense after a while of thinking about it, because he might be wrong. Anyway, proper time is defined by the differential condition, so you shouldn't start with $\tau^2=t^2-x^2$.

Comment: Ok thanks will keep in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that $\tau$ (proper time) is actually a scalar representation of the minkowski 4-vector. In minkowski space we are interested in a vector $u = <t, x, y, z>$ under the "size-measure" $\eta(u,u) = t^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$, i.e. we construct some vector space that represents the spatial and temporal coordinates of a particle $u$ and use $\eta$ to compute distance (or size of the vector in this case) which is analogous to distance in euclidean space $d(x,x) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

So if we take the differential of our 4-vector we see $du = <dt, dx, dy, dz>$ and using our distance function we see the distance $\eta(du,du)  = d\tau^2 =  dt^2 - (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$. Thus, $d\tau = \sqrt{dt^2 - (d|\vec{x}|)^2} \implies \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{d|\vec{x}|^2}{dt^2}}$.

Essentially, the real issue is that we aren't differentiating $\tau$ since $\tau$ is just the size of the 4-vector we're interested in. Instead we are differentiating the components of the vector itself then plugging them into our size function / metric tensor.

Unfortunately, this isn't very clear in linked lecture.

Comment: Ok, thanks though I wasnt able to understand. I am able to point my doubt to a more specific location which is in the here $d\tau^2 = dt^2 - (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$. If I understand correctly then (didnt quite get your pov so speaking in my terms) then $\tau$ is a function of 4 variables ($\tau$ is also scalar quantity) then to get the expression like this we have to differentiate all 5 terms in equation to some common $\lambda$ and then elimante the common $d\lambda$ from the denominators... My question is now why can this be done over here... (Also is this the right question?)

Comment: $\frac{d\tau^2}{d\lambda} = \frac{dt^2}{d\lambda} - (\frac{dx^2}{d\lambda} + \frac{dy^2}{d\lambda} + \frac{dz^2}{d\lambda}) $ ...?

Comment: We're not taking the derivative there, all we're saying is that under this distance function the square of the infinitely small line ($ds^2$) is equal to $dt^2 - (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$. This is easier to understand in euclidean space $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \implies da^2 + db^2 = dc^2$ by the pythagorean theorem - all we're doing is making the line element small.

Comment: It's worth noting that you also can't take the approach you originally mentioned in your post because $x,y,z$ also vary in $t$. This exercise is basically the same as taking the time derivative of arc length (see [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Arc_Length) ). My argument above is non-rigorous but if you desire a rigorous proof I'd read Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin (see pg 136).

Comment: OHK! I think I partially get it. In my approach due to simple definition of partial diff, all other variables excpet for t are kept as constant. (So maybe it wont be good representation of change in $\tau$ wrt time, I guess?) and <x,y,z>  are dependant on time also, so arent really constant. (Ok, I remeber one more thing in the lecture series. proff. did say that any point on space-time can be represented by 3 numbers actually because <x,y,z,t> are not independant of each other).

Comment: To tackle this problem what we did was come back to the bare-bones of differentiation and figured out the relation between $\tau$ and time, which naturally also considers the fact that <x,y,z> are dependant on time....